# SQL how to rearange a string

Tags: sql-server, string, server

HI I have MSSQL server 2008 R2 Enterprise.

I have a table named `Blah` in this table i have a column named `Somethings`.
When i query the column I get the following String(s):-

```
something (something in brackets) somethingelse
somethingtasty  (something in brackets again)
(something in brackets again and again)anothersomething
```

All of the above are variable lengths but all contain something in the brackets.
My question is, is it possible to rearrange the strings so the bracketed text is moved to the beginning?:-

```
(something in brackets)something  somethingelse
(something in brackets again)somethingtasty  
(something in brackets again and again)anothersomething
```

I have tried with `substring`, `charindex` etc but am not getting anywhere fast please help, thanks

Comment: What if it's `something (something in brackets) blah (other things in brackets) blub`?

Comment: You should get the charindex of the opening and closing bracket. The substring between those is the bracketed string, the two other parts of your string (0 -> to indexof '(') and (indexof ')' to end of string) are the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your situation and called the field "Somethings". Here's the code I used to get your desired output. This is assuming you have one set of brackets in the string:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Somethings,CHARINDEX('(',Somethings),CHARINDEX(')',Somethings)-CHARINDEX('(',Somethings)+1) + REPLACE(Somethings,SUBSTRING([Somethings],CHARINDEX('(',Somethings),CHARINDEX(')',Somethings)-CHARINDEX('(',Somethings)+1),'')
FROM TABLE1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would question the logic behind doing this type off string manipulation in the database tier.

But, you can do

```
select 
SUBSTRING(value,charindex('(',value)-1,charindex(')',value) +2 -charindex('(',value))  + -- In ( )
SUBSTRING(value,1,charindex('(',value)-1) +  -- Left of ()
SUBSTRING(value,charindex(')',value)+1,99999), -- Right of ()
value 
 from
(
select 'something (something in brackets) somethingelse' as value 
union
select 'somethingtasty  (something in brackets again)' as value
union
select '(something in brackets again and again)anothersomething' as value
) dummy
```

If you need to do more string extraction and rearrangement maybe use a CRL assembly? the data sample in this question looks to me like it could get more complex, for example having a ) without a ( having (( nested ()'s and so on.

Have a read of [String Splitting SQL vs CRL](http://www.pawlowski.cz/2010/09/string-splitting-t-sql-vs-clr/)

**Conclusion from the website**

> From the test and measuring done in this blog post we can find, that
>   when we need to split relatively small strings with small elements
>   count (<100 elements) then the T-SQL Solution is the quickest possible
>   and unbeatable.
>
> When we have a moderate count of elements in the string (about 100)
>   then it does not matter if we use the T-SQL or CLR-RegEx solution.
>
> Once the count of elements in the string increases (more than 100)
>   then the CLR-RegEx starts being unbeatable and with high counts of
>   elements (more than 1000, or even millions of elements) then the T-SQL
>   solution is nearly unusable as we can see the results of 10 000 rows
>   with 1333 elements each – the T-SQL version took 46 minutes, while the
>   CLR-RegEx took only 1 minute.
>
> Also during all the tests, there was no occurrence of AppDomain
>   Restart/(Unload/Load) when manipulating large strings using the
>   CLR-RegEx solution. On some blogs I have found, that there was some
>   AppDomain unloading and loading when using CLR but with combination of
>   String.Split method. The RegEx solution doesn’t have such problems.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few steps involved. The 1st step is to create 3 substrings. One that captures the (), 1 that captures everything before that, and one that captures everything after that.

So the final answer looks like:

```
SELECT ID,(SUBSTRING(Somethings,CHARINDEX('(',Somethings),(CHARINDEX(')', Somethings)-CHARINDEX('(',Somethings)+1)) + SPACE (1) + SUBSTRING(Somethings,1,CHARINDEX('(',Somethings)-1) + SUBSTRING(Somethings,CHARINDEX(')',Somethings)+1,LEN(Somethings))
FROM Blah
```

The first substring is:

```
SUBSTRING(Somethings,CHARINDEX('(',Somethings),(CHARINDEX(')', Somethings)-CHARINDEX('(',Somethings)+1))
```

It simply gets the string contained between '(' and ')' by using charindex to determine the start and stop positions.

the next one is also simple:

```
SUBSTRING(Somethings,1,CHARINDEX('(',Somethings)-1)
```

It starts at the first character and ends right before '('

The last one :

```
SUBSTRING(Somethings,CHARINDEX(')',Somethings)+1,LEN(Somethings))
```

Starts right after the ')' and ends at the length of the string.

Hope this helps.

Comment: looking through this, you really don't need the stuff function to get your answer. You could just select the combination of substrings.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have another query, using left, right and substring.
This assumes that there is an opening followed by a closing parenthesis in your string, otherwise will fail.

```
select substring(s, charindex('(', s), charindex(')', s) - charindex('(', s)+1)
       + left(s, charindex('(', s)-1)
       + right(s, len(s) - charindex(')', s))
  from smt
```

see [demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/12ffe/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, the best solution was

```
select substring(s, charindex('(', s), charindex(')', s) - charindex('(', s)+1)
       + left(s, charindex('(', s)-1)
       + right(s, len(s) - charindex(')', s))
from smt
```

There was a bracket missing on the end and I also received the following error message:-
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

This was because the function failed because of a missing space which meant it was looking for a substring of length -1 so i added ABS() function to the left part, it now works perfectly.

```
    select substring(s, charindex('(', s), charindex(')', s) - charindex('(', s)+1) + left(s, charindex('(', s)-1) + right(s, len(s) - charindex(')', s))
 from smt
```

Once again thanks for all the help very much appreciated.